# Android - Broadcast Receiver not being fired

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I know this has been asked ALOT on here, but I have been scouring the interwebs for hours and I have even reused some of my previous code for receiving sms' and I got...nothing.

So, here goes, basic app to receive SMS but the app never receives the intent. I thought the intent may be ignored if the text is sent from the same phone but that does not seem to be the case, as other apps pick up the text fine.

Here is my manifest:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.encima.smsreceiver"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
                        <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>
         </activity>
         <receiver android:name=".MessageReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
</manifest>
```

And, here is the receiver, nothing seems to be new here, so I have no idea what the problem is:

```
package com.encima.smsreceiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "Message recieved";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
         Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
         SmsMessage messages =SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);    
         Log.i(TAG,  messages.getMessageBody());
         Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Received : "+messages.getMessageBody(),
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

The debug phone I am using is running 2.2.2 and I have other apps running that detect sms, including some of my own.

Any insight into this would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I got question is this "Log.i(TAG,  messages.getMessageBody());" happening at all ? do you see the log printed ? I mean is your onRceive method get called at all ?

Comment: Nope, I see absolutely nothing, it is like it isn't getting fired. Any ideas?

Comment: okey, lets find the problem :), first comment everything in the onreceive method and leave this line only Log.i("bazz",  "bzzzzzzzzz"); and try if this line get printed

Comment: if the line doesn't get printed it means the linking is not good. All the linking is made in the manifest file but your manifest looks good.

Comment: Line does not get printed, tried various methods in the manifest: "MessageReceiver", ".MessageReceiver" and the whole package. I am starting to think it might be the phone, but other apps are receiving the intent. 
I am at a loss!

Comment: com.encima.smsreceiver.MessageReceiver can be the solution, the MessageReceiver is NOT for sure ,.MessageReceiver sould also work ...

Comment: I have tried the whole package and the class, still doesn't work. Is it something up with the version of Android. The code seems fine and I have been staring at it for hours now. Anything else you can see with it?

Comment: Are you sure your process is still UP? If you stay in background too much you are probably going to be killed to free up memory, check AlarmManager class and try that to keep your process up all the time (and register the receiver on the constructor)

Comment: I am aware that android kills processes but android fires this intent to all registered receivers. As soon as a message is received, all registered receivers should react, it is like it isn't registering for some reason.
I am completely stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the SMS broadcast intent is sent by 
[Context.sendOrderedBroadcast(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29),
if any other app registers the BroadcastReceiver and calls abortBroadcast, the other receiver will not get the broadcast.

To increase the probability of your app receiving the broadcast create an IntentFilter, use [IntentFilter.setPriority](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#setPriority%28int%29).

Comment: I have set the priority to 999, still no luck. Any other ideas? I have even tried android:exported="true" but that does not seem to work either!

Comment: Although, this did not directly answer my question, it did lead me there. It seems that my launcher (Launcher7) was dismissing the broadcast. Not sure how other apps, GoSMS, are getting round that but it is running fine now.

Comment: The provided code has no mention of an IntentFilter. How do we go about adding one to the initial code?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is your problem but you should definitelly try this:

Instead of `".MessageReceiver"` put `android:name = "com.encima.smsreceiver.MessageReceiver"`

This is fix that workout many times for me when something doesn't get called.

Comment: Yeah, I did try that. Still nothing. Thanks for offering the help!