# BroadcastReceiver onReceive is not fired

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to cope with SMS receiving funcions in Android.
I read a lot of related topics on Stackoverflow and other sites and I tried with a very simple Class that simply print on the console that a message has been received and the message, but I cannot figure out why it doesn't work.

I see that similar questions remained unanswered in the past (see [Android - Broadcast Receiver not being fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966902/android-broadcast-receiver-not-being-fired))

Hope someone could find where's the problem with my code.

Code:

```
package com.storassa.android.smsapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
System.out.println("Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
}
if (messages.length > -1) {
System.out.println("Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
        }
    }
}
     }
}
```

And Manifest

```
<manifest package="com.storassa.android.smsapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6" android:targetSdkVersion="6"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
        <receiver android:name="com.storassa.android.smsapp.SmsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, and it's working fine for me.

The post you are referring to has the problem with the setPriority set to 999 and still the broadcast aren't received.

Try setting the priority to Integer.MAX_VALUE or when in xml it should be 2147483647

Some SMS apps will use this Integer.MAX_VALUE as their priority and hence "eat" all messages received.

If it doesn't help setting setPriority to Integer.MAX_VALUE or 2147483647, then try uninstalling all apps that are handling incoming SMS'es and see if the SMS'es comes through to your app.

If this help, then it's one of the applications already installed that are eating the SMS'es.

A work-around for this, would be always to install your application as the first one. By doing this, you will always be the first application receiving the SMS broadcast.

EDIT: setting the priority to Integer.MAX_VALUE or 2147483647 is a hack and should possibly not be used. The setPriority() method only states priority from -1000 - 1000. However I use it in an app myself, but I only handle specific SMS'es received from specific numbers, so I don't see a problem in it.

Comment: Thanks Darwind for your suggestions.
I tried using the Integer.MAX_VALUE without any resut.
I'm using an Android emulator to check the code.
Now I'm trying with a target and I'll let you know.

Comment: Trying with a real target, it seems not working, in the sense that the code does not stop at the breakpoint I put on the first println. BTW, using System.out.println, should I see the printed text on the console window in Eclipse? Should I see anything on the phone?

Comment: How are you sending SMS'es to the emulator?
If the emulator is called something like 5554:[the name you've given the emulator], then from the Emulator control, you should send an SMS to 5554.

Comment: @sthor69 - System.out.println will only display in the logcat. And no you won't see anything on the phone.

Comment: I send SMS with a 'telnet localhost 5554' and then the command 'sms send 1123 Sending a message'

Comment: I'm receiving that nicely as well. ;-)
I assume you're using Eclipse right? Are you looking in the console or in the LogCat (can be found inside the DDMS view)?

Comment: Both. In any case I would be glad just to see the breakpoint working

Comment: Stupid question - are you running the project in debug mode? I get the breakpoint every time I send an SMS to the emulator.
Also, my working project: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27724371/TestSmsReceiver.zip - just import it into Eclipse.

Comment: A question is never stupid. At most it's the answer that is stupid ;-)(I don't remember where I read this aphorism...). I run the code using the "Bug" icon on the upper toolbar and specifying the emulation or the real target. BTW, I cannot open your link (I'm behind a proxy...)

Comment: Hmm a bit of a puzzle - something is definately wrong. It would be great if you could test the project I created, just to see if it's in your code or the emulator. When you send an SMS to the emulator, do you actually receive it? If not, something is eating the SMS'es before they reach your app.

Comment: I can see the received SMS on the phone and on the emulator. I'll try to get your code using a different Internet connection and let you know

Comment: Your app does not work as well. Just to be sure I'm using Eclipse debug in the correct way, I tried with another project and breakpoints are working properly.

Comment: Hmm ok - what emulator are you using?
Also maybe it's better to continue this discussion somewhere else? As we can't chat here because you don't have enough rep, add me on G+: https://plus.google.com/100789210086750421028/

Answer (score 1):

This is happens when you also have installed other application which has high priority then the current one apps, so increase your priority it will start working, i also got this problem many time, in one app my priority was 100 and it was not working but when i changed it to 999, then it starts working,
So try to set different and large no priority and check it again.

Answer (score -1):

```
//In on resume and on pause of actvities register the receiver and also in manifest

    protected void onPause(){

        super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(SmsReceiver ); 

    }



        protected void onResume()
{


            super.onResume();

            registerReceiver(SmsReceiver , 
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

        }


    private BroadcastReceiver SmsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                        }


        };
```

Comment: How would this code even help him? It's just the same as registering the BroadcastReceiver in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
And please explain the code instead of just answering a question with some code.